# How do I know the type of a class variable before i create instance of it?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

Some class for example:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Test(object):
        def test_method(self):
            pass
```

Now, let's check `type` of `varable` from `class object`:

```
>>> type(Test.test_method)
<class 'function'>
```

Nope. From `instance` of `class`?

```
>>> test_var = Test()
>>> type(test_var.test_method)
<class 'method'>
```

Yep, but that's not what I want.
Let's try inspect module:

```
>>> inspect.ismethod(test_var.test_method)
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Test.test_method)
False
```

Nope. **Why?**

Comment: Until it's bound to the instance, the method on the class *is* just a function. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks I'll know. I want somthing like that: `if inspect.ismethod(SomeClass.smth): print("It's a method")` And now I think that it's impossible :)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question - **why** do you want that? And what's the problem with just checking for a function rather than a method, or even e.g. `if callable(SomeClass.smth):`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now I am studying in Python decorators and for example, I wrote such a tool for self-use: `http://pastebin.com/SFqcTdLJ` I just want to give more information in output.